# Logback eclipse RCP configuration

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an Eclipse E4 project with multiple plugins.
I have a ch.qos.logback plugin that contain the following:
logback-classic-1.0.11.jar
logback-core-1.0.11.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar

In the main application package that contains the .product file I have placed a logback-test.xml file under the src folder that contains:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder 
        by default -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] [%logger{50}] - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="DEBUGFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender"> 
    <file>/tmp/Debug.log</file>
    <append>false</append>
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder 
        by default -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] [%logger{50}] - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUGFILE" />
</root>
```

In the Manifest of each package I set a required plugin dependency on the ch.qos.logback plugin.
Logging works fine (both to log file and console) for the main package that contains the .product file. However no logging occurs for any of the plugin packages.
I then tried putting a copy of the logback-test.xml file under the src folder of each plugin-still no logging in other packages. I then tried changing the buddy policy of the ch plugin and the other plugins that require logging as per http://devblog.virtage.com/2012/07/logback-and-eclipse-attaching-logback-xml/
I got an error in the console saying multiple logback-test.xml's were found and logback selected one to use. In each I tried dirrent debug log files and found that logback was using the .xml from a plugin (not main app) but was still only logging output from the main application.
I then tried creating a fragment as per website above but no idea what to do with the fragment. I tried setting it and the ch plugin to singletons - no change.

I then tried setting the VMargs to use a logback-test.xml at a location on the filepath and removed all other logback-test.xml's. Still logging only occurred in the main application not the other plugins.
I then changed the required plugin from ch.qos.plugin to the org.slf4j.api logging then defaulted to all messages to console only and only for main application.

Comment: Eclipse does have its own simple logging could you use that?

Comment: Following http://iloapp.oixx.se/blog/code?NewComment&post=0#comment and setting a VMarg -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/logback-test.xml I got logback to work from all plugins.

Comment: @Greg JUL/Eclipse logger was a back-up plan, but very happy logback is working